# create Sublime2 key binding to mimic shift + arrowL/R

Tags: sublimetext2

In Sublime2, when you hold down shift and use the L/R arrow keys, your cursor moves while selecting text characters.  I want to map this behavior to something else with Sublime key bindings, so I don't have to move my hands to the arrow keys to do this really common action.

I can't figure out how to do this, or if it's possible.  I want to do something like this:

```
{ "keys": ["super+k"], "command": "move_and_select", "args": {"by": "characters", "forward": true} },
{ "keys": ["super+j"], "command": "move_and_select", "args": {"by": "characters", "forward": false} },
```

But I've just made up the `move_and_select` command.  If you use the command `move`, it moves left and right by a character, but I want to move and select.

Is this possible? Can it be done with a python script plugin?

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out. set `"extend": true` in `args` to make the movement also select. So the correct answer should be:

```
{ "keys": ["super+j"], "command": "move", "args": {"by": "characters", "forward": false, "extend": true} },
{ "keys": ["super+l"], "command": "move", "args": {"by": "characters", "forward": true, "extend": true} },
```